# Show page after clicking on a button

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, scriptrunner-for-jira

I would like a web page to be shown after clicking on a button if the issue does not have any components in Jira. I am using a web fragment and a REST api. Here is my code but it is not working Anyone knows how this could be fixed? I am just trying to print a page that says hello world if the issue does not have components. I am using the HTML tags and everything and then using the following line to let the page be shown but it is not working:                          `Response.ok().type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).entity(dialog.toString()).build()`

```
package SuperFeature 

import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response
import com.opensymphony.workflow.WorkflowException
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

mounaGenerate(httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["jira-users"]) 
{
          MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->
         def log1 = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")
          def issueId = queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long

            Issue myissue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(issueId)
            def issueKey = myissue.getKey()           
            def componentNames = myissue.getComponents()*.name

          log1.warn("MOUNA componentNames "+componentNames)


              if(componentNames.empty) {

                      log1.warn("MOUNA EMPTY")
                       
            
                        def dialog =
                            """<html>
                                <head>
                                <title>Hello World</title>
                                </head>
                                <body id="jira" class="aui-layout aui-theme-default">
                                <h1>Hello world</h1>
                                </body>
                                </html>
                                """
              
                         Response.ok().type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).entity(dialog.toString()).build()











              }else{
                          log1.warn("MOUNA componentNames NOT EMPTY")

              }
}
```